# MYSQL/PHP Unable to save result set

Tags: php, mysql

I am running a PHP script which basically tries to find matching names from MYSQL database and then assigns the same number to records with identical names.

My problem is that the number of records are around 1.5 million. The script always  runs for about 14 hours every time and gives this error : mysql_query unable to save result set in xx on line xxx. and phpmyadmin gives this error #2008 out of memeory

Here is my php code

```
mysql_query("SET SQL_BIG_TABLES=1");

$res = mysql_query("SELECT company_name, country, id FROM proj")
       or die (mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    $res1 = mysql_query("SELECT company_name, id FROM proj WHERE country='$row[1]'"+
          "AND id<>'$row[2]'") or die ("here".mysql_error().mysql_errno());

    while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($res1, MYSQL_NUM)) {
          //My calculations here 
    }
}
```

Comment: "The script always runs for about 14 hours" That sound you heard was me falling out of my chair.

Comment: @Jared epic. @user consider using indexes, removing objects from memory, chunking your processing. And last but not least, increasing the memory of PHP `ini_set('memory_limit','1G');` or whatever you are comfortable with.

Comment: @user, judging by your code, your first query gets all 1.5 mil, your second query gets all the queries for a given country, but this repeats for each query, meaning you just squared your processing. what is it you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: @khez comparing the company_name field of each record with others to match them based on how they sound

Comment: That piece of code clearly does not do that.

Comment: my calculationas part does it which i havent posted

Comment: my memory limit is already set as 1G in my php.ini

Answer (score 5):

Ok. Your query is incredibly inefficient. You say in a comment that there's 1.5 million rows.

1. Outside query creates a result set with all 1.5 million rows
2. Inside query creates a new result set with all 1.5 million rows, EXCEPT the row that has the same of the row you're looping on. So basically you're doing 1.5 million * (1.5 million - 1) rows = 
   2,249,998,500,000 = 2.25 trillion rows

In other words, not only incredibly inefficient - it's absolutely ludicrous. Given you seem to want to fetch only rows by country, why not do something like:

```
$sql1 = "SELECT DISTINCT country FROM proj";
$res1 = mysql_query($sql1) or die(mysql_error());

while($row1 = mysql_fetch_associ($res1)) {
    $country = $row1['country'];
    $escaped_country = mysql_real_escape_string($country);
    $sql2 = "SELECT company_name, id FROM proj WHERE country='$country'";
    $res2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());
    while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2)) {
       ... calculations ...
    }
}
```

This'd fetch only 1.5 million + # of country records from the database, which is far far far less than the 2.3 trillion your version has.

Comment: I did not understand. What I am doing is this                            1. In the first query fetch 1.5 million company names and their country                                                               2. then I need to find companies names in the same country which are same as the one above so at the minimum I need to compare each record with every record with the same country name.

Comment: Yes, but why do you have to fetch the country for every company? There's only so many countries on this planet, so fetch a list of distinct countries, then process from there. instead of 1.5 million rows in the first query, you'd have about 200 or so at most.